# Having troubles with viewing a product in PHP & SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, online-store

I wanted to make an automatic table display all the products from the database, where you can click on its name and view the whole details of the product. And my idea was that it wouldn't bring you to another .php file, but rather you'll still be on the same page so you wouldn't waste time on creating multiple .php files of every products. 
The problem is, whenever I click on a product, it wouldn't load the product's information (the only detail is the description by the way).

**Error**
 *Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp\www\goldenrod\index.php on line 56*

This is the database connection:

```
<?php
//Database Connections
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lionsierra_db') or die("Cannot find specified server");

//Product Database
$db_products = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
$products = mysqli_query($dbc, $db_products);
?>
```

And this is the function:

```
<?php
//View product
if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
    while($product=mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {
    $products['ID'] = $_GET['view_product'];
    //Display a product
    echo "<p><span>
        <span style='font-weight:bold;'>" . $products['ID']['name'] . "</span><br/>
        <span>$" . $products['ID']['price'] . "</span><br/>
        <span>" . $products['ID']['category'] . "</span><br/>
        <span>" . $products['ID']['description'] . "</span>
    </p>";
    }
}
//View all products
echo '<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Category</th>
    </tr>';
    while($product=mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td><a href='./index.php?view_product=" . $product['ID'] . "'>". $product['name'] . "</a></td>
            <td>" . $product['price'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $product['category'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
        $ID = $product['ID'];
    }
?>
```

I'm still fairly new to PHP and SQL, and it would be grateful if you guys could help me out.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp\www\goldenrod\index.php on line 56

Comment: So what's on line 56?

Comment: $products['ID'] = $_GET['view_product'];

Comment: @ohgodwhy just handed you the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, but now I'm having problems with the  mysqli_stmt_bind_result()  and mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Comment: Can't help you if you don't post what the error is...

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt_bind_result() in C:\wamp\www\goldenrod\index.php on line 59

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\wamp\www\goldenrod\index.php on line 61

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_result($view_product_statement); = line 59

Comment: while($product=mysqli_fetch_assoc($view_product_statement)) = line 61

Answer (score 1):

The issue resides here:

```
 if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
     while($product=mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {
```

Looks like you're just re-using a `MySQLI` query here. Instead, you should be altering the query depending on the `productID`. Let's see what that looks like:

```
if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
    //now let's build out our query
    $view_product_statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($view_product_statement, 'i', $_GET['view_product']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($view_product_statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($view_product_statement);

    while($product=mysqli_fetch_assoc($view_product_statement)){
        //now $product holds reference to the one we're trying to view.
    } 
    mysqli_stmt_close($view_product_statement);
}
```

I've used `prepared statements` in my above to help sanitize your user input in such a way that you help avoid `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Now I'm having problems with  having the wrong parameter for mysqli_stmt_bind_result and the parameter of mysqli_fetch_assoc is expecting mysqli_result